# Launch Party ad

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, advertising, launch

Could Jin please design an ad for our Launch Party, along the lines of the text below?

(Jin and the community should feel free to edit the text.)

- The main ad we need would be an image suitable for pasting into blog posts and emails.
- Secondarily, it would be nice to have an 8X11.5" PDF for printing out (or emailing for those who can't embed images in their emails).

> On June 3, from 2pm to 3pm EDT,J
>
> Join Mi Yodeya - Stack Exchange, the online community for Jewish Q&A
>
> for our online radio Launch Party!
>
> Featuring
>
> A conversation with Rabbi Gil Student, Founder and Author of the
>   Hirhurim / TorahMusings.com blog
>
> on
>
> Learning with the Crowd: Judaism on the Internet
>
> And also
>
> - Your calls
> - Games
> - Words of Torah from Mi Yodeya community members
> - Globe-spanning Lechaims!
>
> Come to LaunchParty.yodeya.com to listen live and join in.

Possible stripped-down version:

> Mi Yodeya - Stack Exchange
>
> Online Radio Launch Party
>
> June 3, 2012, 2pm - 3pm EDT
>
> LaunchParty.yodeya.com
>
> Featuring:
>
> - Rabbi Gil Student of TorahMusings.com
> - Your calls
> - Games
> - Words of Torah
> - Lechaims

Or simply

> Mi Yodeya - Stack Exchange
>
> Online Radio Launch Party
>
> June 3, 2012, 2pm - 3pm EDT
>
> LaunchParty.yodeya.com
>
> Featuring Rabbi Gil Student of TorahMusings.com and your calls

Comment: will it be recorded for listening to later?

Comment: @Menachem, Yes; it will be archived.

Comment: Yep I'll work on this. For the web Ad image, do you have a rough estimate on the dimension? (in pixels)

Comment: @Jin, Thanks! I guess that of the [standard web ad sizes](http://www.espressographics.com/text/ad_size.html), what I think would work best for this purpose would be either Medium Rectangle (300X250) or Large Rectangle (336X280), but I don't have much experience in web ads, so I defer to your or anyone else's judgement.

Comment: @Jin, I realize that not all of the text I listed above will necessarily fit into these sizes. Like I said, please feel free to edit it down. Please make sure to include the names "Rabbi Gil Student" and either "Hirhurim" or "TorahMusings.com", as these are well-known names to our target audience, and we're hoping that they'll help us bring in people from outside SE.

Comment: @Jin, one more note: Starting tonight at sundown will be Sabbath, and that will be followed immediately by a 48-hour (24-hour in Israel) holiday of [Shavu'ot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shavuot). So, most of the most active members of this community will be off of the site from sundown tonight until late Monday night, so don't be surprised if you (are working on the weekend and) happen to ask for feedback during that period and don't get any immediately.

Comment: @Jin ... and I can't get at chat right now, though I'll check in later today. I saw that you pinged me with respect to something about the ad capacity. I've edited in two possible stripped-down texts above, but feel free to edit.

Comment: @IsaacMoses thanks for the edit. I think the text works for smaller Ads. I'll be posting various sizes of the Ad designs soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the 729 x 80 px and 220 x 250px versions of the Ad. If there are other sizes you need, please let me know.

[image: Ad 729px]

[image: Ad 220px]

edit: added 8.5"x11" print version. Please click to view full resolution version. [Here's a PDF](http://static.yodeya.com/Mi_Yodeya_Launch_Party_June3_2012.pdf) of it.

[image: Ad PDF]

Comment: We can advertise on our own site. Vote this up as a community add http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1141/759

Comment: Thanks! They look great. Could you please change the referenced URL to LaunchParty.yodeya.com? That's the landing page for the party itself.

Comment: If the text for launchparty.yodeya.com doesn't fit, you can use launch.yodeya.com, which I just assigned

Comment: @IsaacMoses I wonder if we'll even need the URL? The ad banner should already link to the launch party page itself right? For print materials the url is needed.

Comment: @Jin, if people paste one of these images into an email or social media, they may not be able to or remember to link it. It will work most robustly if the image itself contains all the information necessary to get right to the party.

Comment: @IsaacMoses good point. I have updated the images.

Comment: @Jin Thanks for the update!

Comment: @IsaacMoses added the 8.5.x11 print version.

Comment: @Jin Yet you seem to still be planning on posting it shortly...

Comment: @DoubleAA ha I forgot to edit it out. Edited.

Comment: @Jin Thanks very much again!