# PLEASE promote the Launch Party far and wide

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, advertising, launch

[image: Launch Party Ad Image]

As you hopefully know by now, we're celebrating our recent launch out of beta with an online radio launch party this coming Sunday. This is going to be both a fun and edifying celebration for community members and a unique, exciting opportunity to promote our site and community to the wider world.

So, if you were waiting for the perfect time to promote Mi Yodeya to your friends, you need wait no longer. This is it.

Please take one or more of:

- The URL http://launchparty.yodeya.com
- Any of the promotional text [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1133/2)
- Any of the [ad images](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1140/2) that Jin made for us or the [PDF](http://static.yodeya.com/Mi_Yodeya_Launch_Party_June3_2012.pdf) based on them
- An invitation to [this event](https://www.facebook.com/events/422433937791027/) on Facebook
- Your own words about why you like Mi Yodeya and why you're excited about this party

and post them to:

- Your social networks (FaceBook, Twitter, G+, Pinterest, whatever it is you're into)
- Your email buddies
- Your blog
- Your favorite blogger's email
- Your Jewish organization's physical bulletin board
- Anywhere else relevant you can think of

Let's make this a huge bash!

Comment: The link in the ad is dead thus far. People will want to see what's there even before the party, to know what this "mi yodeya" thing is.

Comment: @msh210 Which link? Isn't it [launchparty.yodeya.com](http://launchparty.yodeya.com), and doesn't that go to the right place?

Comment: It is that URL, and that goes nowhere (it times out).

Comment: @msh210 not for me. That's weird. For me, it goes right to http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/mi-yodeya-launch-party . Can anyone else confirm/deny what behavior their browser delivers for launchparty.yodeya.com?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/oXrdq.png

Comment: @msh210 It's a URL redirect. Would that ping? I get the same behavior from ping as you do.

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: launchparty.yodeya.com works for me.

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: works for me too

Comment: Then I'll assume it'll work for whomever I send the link to.